# Passkey creation with Google Credential Manager fails without an `authenticatorSelection` claim in the request

Tags: android, webauthn, credential-manager, passkey

After following [Sign in your user with Credential Manager](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys#format-json-request), I adapted it to my use case and backend.
Creating a passkey worked fine with Samsung Pass and Dashlane, but not with Google Password Manager that raised an unhelpful `androidx.credentials.exceptions.CreateCredentialCustomException: 34000: null`.

After a while of trial and error, I realized that my backend's `PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions` was lacking an `authenticatorSelection` claim, unlike the example in the Android guide.

This claim is not marked as required in [WebAuthn 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dictionary-makecredentialoptions) spec. Still, the presence of a non-empty `authenticatorSelection` claim is what makes passkey creation with Google Password Manager work. I also isolated this behaviour using the [example app](https://github.com/android/identity-samples/tree/main/CredentialManager) from android repos.

I couldn't find documentation on this requirement. Is this just bad spec implementation from Google Password Manager? Did I misunderstand the spec? Did I miss a piece of documentation ?